# x86 assembly stack layout confusion

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, disassembly

I have two different binaries and the disassemblies of their `main` functions start like this:

```
 80483d4:   55                      push   %ebp
 80483d5:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80483d7:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 80483da:   83 ec 20                sub    $0x20,%esp
 80483dd:   8d 45 08                lea    0x8(%ebp),%eax
 80483e0:   89 44 24 1c             mov    %eax,0x1c(%esp)
```

And the other one is this:

```
 80483d4:   8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx            
 80483d8:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp         
 80483db:   ff 71 fc                pushl  -0x4(%ecx)                
 80483de:   55                      push   %ebp                     
 80483df:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp    
...
 80483e6:   89 4d f0                mov    %ecx,-0x10(%ebp)
```

First one was compiled under GNU/Linux 2.6.24 and second one was compiled under GNU/Linux 2.6.9. For most of the time, I understand as `0x4(%esp)` as return address and `0x8(%esp)` as first argument. Apparently, first binary used `0x8(%ebp)` -- its same as `0x8(%esp)` before alignment happened -- as first argument whereas second binary used `0x4(%esp)` as first argument and it made me confused why it did. Is this because they were compiled under different version of GNU/Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that both refer to the first argument. The reason for the difference in displacement between `8(%ebp)` in the first example and `4(%esp)` in the second is that one takes place before the saving of `ebp` and the other takes place afterwards.

To make it entirely clear:

```
movl 4(%esp), %eax # here, the first argument is at esp + 4
push %ebp          # push has the effect of esp -= 4
movl %esp, %ebp
movl 8(%ebp), %eax # here, the first argument is at esp + 8 (or equivalently, ebp + 8)
```

An additional point of interest is that aligning the stack pointer is done before saving it to `ebp` in one binary, and after saving it in another. That seems odd to me - I can only assume that in the latter case the old value of `esp` is recalculated from `ecx` at some point before main returns.

Comment: wait... I'm still lost x( so how come esp + 4 is pointing first argument and after ..... ah ebp was pushed!!!!!! I got it. I don't know why I missed that point! how stupid I am..